# iphone basic release question

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, release

When i add a new subview, i cant immediately release the controller after displaying. How should i release this viewController?

I was thinking about using a property for the viewController, and use delegation to notify for removing the view and releasing it?

Is this the best way to do it? or should i do something with autorelease?

Ton.

Comment: You should add a little code snippet as an example for the challenge you are facing. Your assets seem to be a view, a viewController and something that you call displaying; which I suppose is your word for adding the viewController/view to a visible view/window. Please elaborate and you will get help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to have a shot at answering this rather vague question. I think what you are doing is creating a new subview and then releasing it. What you need to do is add it to your main view. Something like:

```
[myView addSubview.newSubview];
```

Once you have done this myView owns the subview and you can release it without hassles.